# best practise firebase data structure

Tags: angularjs, json, data-structures, firebase, angularfire

Hello I'am just startet with firebase and AngularFire and have a basic questions whats the best practise about database structure and queries.

i have a app with a user login and each user can create and store reports and so I'am thinking of two ways how to build up the data structure in firebase:

First:

```
{
  "reports" : {
    "userid_1" : {
      "reportid_1" : {
        "reportTitle" : "some title",
        "reportMsg" : "some text"
      },
      "reportid_2" : {
        "reportTitle" : "some title",
        "reportMsg" : "some text"
      },
      "reportid_3" : {
        "reportTitle" : "some title",
        "reportMsg" : "some text"
      }

    },
    "userid_2" : {
      "reportid_1" : {
        "reportTitle" : "some title",
        "reportMsg" : "some text"
      },
      "reportid_2" : {
        "reportTitle" : "some title",
        "reportMsg" : "some text"
      },
      "reportid_3" : {
        "reportTitle" : "some title",
        "reportMsg" : "some text"
      }

    }
  }
}
```

then i can do i query like:

```
var ref_reports = new Firebase("https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/reports/"+userid+"/");
```

Second:

```
{
  "reports": {
    "report_id_1": {
      "userid": "userid_1",
      "reportdata": {
        "reportTitle": "some title",
        "reportMsg": "some text"
      }
    },
    "report_id_2": {
      "userid": "userid_2",
      "reportdata": {
        "reportTitle": "some title",
        "reportMsg": "some text"
      }
    },
    "report_id_3": {
      "userid": "userid_1",
      "reportdata": {
        "reportTitle": "some title",
        "reportMsg": "some text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then make query and filter the data by the userid:

```
var ref_reports = new Firebase("https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com/reports/");
```

So is it better to filter the received firebase array or is it better to filter the data already with the referenz?

Thanks

Comment: This depends on how you are going to use the data. There is no best solution for every situation.

Comment: You might want to study this classic [Firebase blog post](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html) and the [Firebase guide on structuring data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html).